# Can't connect to my gateway address (refused to connect.)

Tags: port-forwarding

So for the last days I've been trying to portforward a server for a game (TF2 to be specific), and for some reason I can't access my router's admin page.

I do have internet connection and have no problems surfing the web, but when I type my gateway address into chrome, it gives me a "192.168.10.1 refused to connect" (this address I got from running the "route" command).

I've tried the standard addresses (192.168.1.1 & 192.168.1.0 & 192.168.0.1 and finally 192.168.0.0), none of them work. I've also tried restarting my router and turning off my firewall - obviously didn't help either.

I'm not sure what to do here, I've looked up many sites on this issue on google but to no avail. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

What brand of router do you have? You can check what the default address would be on google by looking up the product.

Comment: I have a Telsey, model cpl7. All their stated addresses don't work either.

Comment: Have you tried a different port? Maybe it's on 443 for ssl. It's also entirely possible that there's some sort of acl preventing your access

Comment: No I have not tried that (wasn't aware that ports might be different), just tried it but same result. Can't connect.